# Script to generate JSON report for mocha test report while using babel-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, babeljs, package.json

I am using mocha and babel-cli and I am able to run mocha test using script

```
"mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive"
```

When **I am not using** babel I am able to generate the JSON report using script

```
./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -R json> report
```

Does anyone have solution(script) that how to get json report **when using babel with mocha**

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Do you get a specific error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Script to get json report file for mocha test when using babel with es6 standard code.

```
"./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -R json> report.json --require babel-core/register --recursive"
```

babel dependencies in package.json file -

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1"
  }
```